# Масштаб на мобилке

Tags: html, css

На сайте у `body` и некоторых элементов (например фиксированное меню сверху) в CSS установлено свойство `min-height: 750px;`.
При просмотре с мобильного изначально страница выглядела так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После добавления `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />` стало так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать чтобы минимальный размер был `750px`?
Это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какое значение width? если можно, то сбросьте часть css кода

Comment: @MaxManchak, `100%`, в некоторых местах `max-width: 1200px`.

Comment: Если картинка задана через background-image, попробуйте задать свойство background-size:contain;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, никто не смог ответить правильно.
А решение оказалось довольно простым.
**НЕ** использовать `width` в `meta viewport`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=750, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

Comment: А что произойдет на 320px разрешении? скробар?

Comment: На мобиле шириной 320 покажет ширину 750. Без горизонтального скролла будет масштабировать.

Comment: Спасибо, нужно попробовать.

Answer (score 4):

Исходя из предоставленных данных, у Вас все работает. А растягивается картинка добавьте свойство картинке не cover а просто 100% без репита

```css
nav{
  min-height: 750px;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybu0U.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav>
</nav>
```

Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/Rusic/hxz84mfg/5/

Comment: Дело не в картинке, а в самом документе, он изначально вылезает за пределы. | Я понимаю, что нужно делать адаптивную вёрстку, но суть вопроса в том, что можно ли заставить элемент "вогнать" в определённую ширину.

Comment: Только я бы для использования картинки, удалили точку внизу и указал цвет соответствующий фону